# AccountRq iterator attribute is not wroking, QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream

Tags: sdk, quickbooks

When ever i try to use iterator attribute in AccountRq following exception occurred
HRESULT = 0x80040400
Message: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="11"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<AccountQueryRq iteratorID="Start">
<MaxReturned>10</MaxReturned>
<FromModifiedDate>any date here</FromModifiedDate>
</AccountQueryRq>           
</QBXMLMsgsRq>      
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the [QuickBooks OSR](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html), AccountQuery *does not support* iterators.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <AccountQueryRq metaData="ENUMTYPE">
...
```

(notice no iteratorID=... attribute in the XML definition)

Generally, the size of the Chart of Accounts is teeny tiny enough that you don't need iterators to grab all of the accounts at once.